# Am I specifying my coordinates properly for a cube map?

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

So far, my understanding of cube mapping has been that 3D texture coordinates need to be specified for each vertex used within a cube, as opposed to `(u,v)` coordinates for 2D textures.

**Some Assumptions**

- Cube maps use normalized vertices to represent the texture coordinates of a triangle.
- These normalized vertices are akin to the actual vertices specified: the normalized texture coordinates use the magnitude of their corresponding vertices.
- Thus, if a vertex has a unit magnitude of 1, then its normalized texture coordinate, N, is 1.0f  / sqrt(3.0f );

Which of these assumptions are correct and incorrect? If any are incorrect, please specify why.

**Edit**

While not necessary, what would be appreciated is an example or, rather, an idea of what the recommended way of going about it would be - using programmable pipeline.

Comment: Sorry, but your terminology it completely messed up.

Comment: Yup, I realized that after I did some more digging. You're referring to the fact that it uses vertex normals instead, right?

Comment: No, I'm not referring to normals. Cubemaps use 3-dimensional texture coordinates. However the texture coordinate does not designate a position, but a direction, i.e. a ray originating from the center of the cube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cubemaps are textures that consist of 6 quadratic textures arranged in a cube topology. The only key quantity of cubemap texture coordinates is their direction. In a cubemap its texels are addressed by the direction of a vector originating in the cube's center. It doesn't matter which length the texture coordinate vector has. Say you got two cube map texture coordinates

```
(1, 1, 0.5)
```

and

```
(2, 2, 1)
```

they both address the same cubemap texel.

Comment: `addressed by the direction of a vector originating in the cube's center` so does this mean it uses surface normals as opposed to vertex normals, then?

Comment: @blissfreak: No, it doesn't use normals. Neither uses it vertex positions or anything else than simple, ordinary texture coordinates specified using glTexCoord or texture coordinate attribute vertex array, or texture coordinates generated in a shader. The main difference for cubemaps is, that for them is, that their 3d texture coordinates don't specify a position, but a direction: It's the direction of a ray originating in the cube's center and where it hits one of the cube's faces that's the position on the cubemap itself.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification. Would you mind appending to your answer the recommended way of going about it?